# Enforce class template specializations to provide one or more methods

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm using a "traits" pattern where I have a base case expressed as a class template

```cpp
template <class>
struct DoCache {
  constexpr static bool value = false;
};
```

and I expect users to specialize for their types:

```cpp
template <>
struct DoCache<MyType> {
  constexpr static bool value = true;

  static void write2Cache(MyType const&) { /* implementation */ }
  static optional<MyType> readFromCache(string name) { /* implementation */ }
};
```

The typical use is to retrieve and use this as:

```cpp
// Define a variable template
template <class T>
constexpr bool do_cache_v = DoCache<T>::value;

// Use the above trait in compile time branching:
if constexpr (do_cache_v<T>)
{
  write2Cache(arg);
}
```

---

There's two problems I have with this code:

1. A user is only indirectly enforced to provide a "value" member when specializing, let alone making it the proper value (i.e. `true`). By indirectly I mean they'll get a bunch of compilation errors that one can only solve if they know the answer beforehand.
2. There's no way of "requiring" them to create the two needed methods, namely `write2Cache` and `readFromCache`, let alone having (const) correct types.

In some code-bases I've seen the considerations above being tackled by defining a generator macro like:

```cpp
#define CACHABLE(Type, Writer, Reader) ...
```

- Is there a better way to it?
- Can concepts be used to restrict the way a specialization looks?
- Is there a C++17 compatible way?

an answer to any of the above is appreciated

Comment: It seems like a perfect use case for CRTP here. Make a *base* class that makes use of the child's `writeToCache`. For the code to compile, they need to write an implementation for this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### C++17: Curiously recurring template pattern

It seems like a suitable use case for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template<typename T> 
struct DoCache {
    void write2Cache() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->write2Cache();
    }
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
void write2Cache(DoCache<T>& t) {
    t.write2Cache();
}

struct MyType : DoCache<MyType>
{
    void write2Cache() { /* ... */ }
};

int main() {
    MyType mt{};
    write2Cache(mt);
}
```

Instead of requiring clients to specialize a library type over their own types, you require them to implementes their own types in-terms-of (static polymorphism) the contract/facade of the library type.

---

#### C++20: Concepts

With concepts you can skip polymorphism entirely:

```
template<typename T>
concept DoCachable = requires(T t) {
    t.write2Cache();
};

template<DoCachable T>
void write2Cache(T& t) {
    t.write2Cache();
}

struct MyType {
    void write2Cache() { /* ... */ }
};

struct MyBadType {};

int main() {
    MyType mt{};
    write2Cache(mt);

    MyBadType mbt{};
    write2Cache(mbt);  // error: ...
      // because 'MyBadType' does not satisfy 'DoCachable'
      // because 't.write2Cache()' would be invalid: no member named 'write2Cache' in 'MyBadType'
}
```

However again placing requirements on the definition site of client type (as opposed to specialization which can be done after the fact).

---

#### Trait-based conditional dispatch to `write2Cache()`?

> But how is the trait `do_cache_v` exposed this way?

**C++17 approach**

- Since the CRTP-based approach offers an "is-a"-relationsship via inheritance, you could simply implement a trait for "is-a `DoCache<T>`":

  ```
  #include <type_traits>

  template<typename>
  struct is_do_cacheable             : std::false_type {};

  template<typename T>
  struct is_do_cacheable<DoCache<T>> : std::true_type {};

  template<typename T>
  constexpr bool is_do_cacheable_v{is_do_cacheable<T>::value};

  // ... elsewhere
  if constexpr(is_do_cacheable_v<T>) {
      write2Cache(t);        
  }
  ```

**C++20 approach**

- With concepts, the concept itself can be used as a trait:

  ```
  if constexpr(DoCachable<T>) {
      write2Cache(t);        
  }
  ```

Comment: @Evg Then I think OP's existing approach of requiring specializations is the way to go.

Comment: I removed my first comment, sorry. I should give this approach more thought.

Comment: @Evg I'm re-thinking the above myself as the static functions isn't really needed when going for CRTP or Concepts; in progress of updating.

Comment: @dfrib But how is the trait `do_cache_v` exposed this way?

Comment: @LorahAttkins Last time I did something similar, I simply detected if `DoCache` is specialized for a particular `T` and if it is, used that specialization. You can detect if `DoCache` is specialized by checking that `DoCache<T>` is a complete type.

Comment: @LorahAttkins Is the trait needed at all? As I understood from your example it's only there to know whether the type supports a specialized implementation or not?

Comment: @dfrib exactly, if it's not I take a different code path - for example call the write to cache / read from cache methods. Using CRTP I can't  think of a way to compile time branch

Comment: @LorahAttkins Adding a separate trait for `do_cache_v` is quite simple for both approaches. I've expanded the answer with details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a concept to **sanity check specializations**. Here you only need to provide the correct, by **name** & **type**, methods hence the `::value` member in `DoCache` can be deprecated:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept Cacheable = requires (T const& obj) { 
    { DoCache<T>::write2Cache(obj) } 
        -> std::same_as<void>;
    { DoCache<T>::readFromCache(std::string{}) } 
        -> std::same_as<std::optional<T>>; 
};
```

Usage is similar to the trait:

```cpp
if constexpr (Cacheable<MyStruct>)
```

and enforces proper specialization of `DoCache`.

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f660b41ffda384c7)

The method shown above implies that a user is allowed to specialize `DoCache` in an improper way, resulting in a "non cacheable" type. To prevent this from happening you can:

1. Use defensive programming by placing a `static_assert(Cacheable<MyStruct>)` after the specialization.
2. Leverage a `constexpr static value` member again and enforce an [all or nothing policy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afc81509208b816d) in specializations, i.e. either a specialization is not provided for the type, or the provided specialization contains all members as specified in the concept. This implies you'll use a trait whose template parameter is the concept.